# Example for pairwise triangularizable but not all three. 

Tags: linear-algebra

I am not able give an example for the following problem on [simultaneous triangularization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangular_matrix#Simultaneous_triangularisability). So, I thought I will post it here.

Give an example of three linear transformations $A,B$ and $C,$ such that the pairs $\lbrace A,B\rbrace$, $\lbrace B,C\rbrace$ and $\lbrace A,C\rbrace$ are simultaneously triangularizable, but the triplet $\lbrace A,B,C\rbrace$ is not simultaneously triangularizable.

Thank you.

ADDED LATER: For my need, I am looking for an example of linear transformations acting on vector spaces over $\mathbb{C}.$

Comment: Silly extension: what abstract simplicial complexes can be realized with matrices corresponding to vertices and sets of simultaneously triangularizable matrices as simplices?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a simple example:
$$ A = \begin{pmatrix}
        0 & 1 & \\
          & 0 & \\
          &   & 0
       \end{pmatrix}, 
   \quad
   B = \begin{pmatrix}
        0 & & \\
          & 0 & 1 \\
          &   & 0
       \end{pmatrix},
   \quad
   C = \begin{pmatrix}
         0 & & \\
           & 0 & \\
         1 &   & 0
       \end{pmatrix} .
$$
Every pair can be  triangularized (by a permutation matrix, by the way), but $A$, $B$ and $C$ have no common eigenvector, and so these three matrices can't be simultaneously triangularized.

Comment: Nailed it with such a simple answer! Thanks.